# How to fill a multifield slot from single slots?

Tags: clips

The problem is to fill a multifield slot from single slots. To specify the idea, there a set of facts of the same template where some single slots are allready filled, and another template where a multifield slots are not yet filled. It is need to fill the latter with values of single slots values from  single slots facts belonging to another template.
For Instance, here the templates declared:

```
(deftemplate Connexion 
             (slot ID-BUS)
             (multislot CB-CLOSED (default nil))
             (multislot CB-OPEN (default nil)))

(deftemplate CB 
             (slot ID-BUS) 
             (slot NUM-CB)   
             (slot STATE-CB (allowed-integers -1 0 1)(default -1)))

(deftemplate State-Vector
             (multislot CB-CLOSED (default nil))
             (multislot CB-OPEN (default nil)))
```

Suppose a following facts:

```
(deffacts Some-Facts

(State-Vector (CB-CLOSED 1 4 5 6 7)(CB-OPEN 2 3 8 9))

(CB (ID-BUS B1)(NUM-CB 1)(STATE-CB 1))
(CB (ID-BUS B1)(NUM-CB 4)(STATE-CB 1))
(CB (ID-BUS B1)(NUM-CB 6)(STATE-CB 1))

(CB (ID-BUS B2)(NUM-CB 2)(STATE-CB 0))
(CB (ID-BUS B2)(NUM-CB 5)(STATE-CB 1))
(CB (ID-BUS B2)(NUM-CB 8)(STATE-CB 0))

(CB (ID-BUS B3)(NUM-CB 3)(STATE-CB 0))
(CB (ID-BUS B3)(NUM-CB 7)(STATE-CB 1))
(CB (ID-BUS B3)(NUM-CB 9)(STATE-CB 0))

(Connexion (ID-BUS B1)(CB-CLOSED nil)(CB-OPEN nil))
(Connexion (ID-BUS B2)(CB-CLOSED nil)(CB-OPEN nil))
(Connexion (ID-BUS B3)(CB-CLOSED nil)(CB-OPEN nil)))
```

What was required is to fill multifield slots CB-CLOSED and CB-OPEN belonging to template Connexion from facts belonging to template CB. The expected results will be something like this:

```
(Connexion (ID-BUS B1)(CB-CLOSED  1 4 6)(CB-OPEN nil))
(Connexion (ID-BUS B2)(CB-CLOSED 5)(CB-OPEN 2 8)))
(Connexion (ID-BUS B3)(CB-CLOSED 7)(CB-OPEN 3 9)))
```

Question: How did I proceed to obtain this results ?

Answer (score 0):

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate Connexion 
   (slot ID-BUS)
   (multislot CB-CLOSED (default nil))
   (multislot CB-OPEN (default nil)))
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate CB 
   (slot ID-BUS) 
   (slot NUM-CB)   
   (slot STATE-CB (allowed-integers -1 0 1)(default -1)))
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate State-Vector
   (multislot CB-CLOSED (default nil))
   (multislot CB-OPEN (default nil)))
CLIPS>              
(deffacts Some-Facts
   (State-Vector (CB-CLOSED 1 4 5 6 7)(CB-OPEN 2 3 8 9))

   (CB (ID-BUS B1)(NUM-CB 1)(STATE-CB 1))
   (CB (ID-BUS B1)(NUM-CB 4)(STATE-CB 1))
   (CB (ID-BUS B1)(NUM-CB 6)(STATE-CB 1))

   (CB (ID-BUS B2)(NUM-CB 2)(STATE-CB 0))
   (CB (ID-BUS B2)(NUM-CB 5)(STATE-CB 1))
   (CB (ID-BUS B2)(NUM-CB 8)(STATE-CB 0))

   (CB (ID-BUS B3)(NUM-CB 3)(STATE-CB 0))
   (CB (ID-BUS B3)(NUM-CB 7)(STATE-CB 1))
   (CB (ID-BUS B3)(NUM-CB 9)(STATE-CB 0))

   (Connexion (ID-BUS B1)(CB-CLOSED nil)(CB-OPEN nil))
   (Connexion (ID-BUS B2)(CB-CLOSED nil)(CB-OPEN nil))
   (Connexion (ID-BUS B3)(CB-CLOSED nil)(CB-OPEN nil)))
CLIPS>    
(defrule populate-connexion
   ?c <- (Connexion (ID-BUS ?name) (CB-CLOSED nil) (CB-OPEN nil))
   =>
   (bind ?closed (create$))
   (bind ?open (create$))
   (do-for-all-facts ((?cb CB)) (eq ?cb:ID-BUS ?name)
      (if (eq ?cb:STATE-CB 1)
         then
         (bind ?closed (create$ ?closed ?cb:NUM-CB))
         else
         (bind ?open (create$ ?open ?cb:NUM-CB))))
   (modify ?c (CB-CLOSED ?closed) (CB-OPEN ?open)))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (State-Vector (CB-CLOSED 1 4 5 6 7) (CB-OPEN 2 3 8 9))
f-2     (CB (ID-BUS B1) (NUM-CB 1) (STATE-CB 1))
f-3     (CB (ID-BUS B1) (NUM-CB 4) (STATE-CB 1))
f-4     (CB (ID-BUS B1) (NUM-CB 6) (STATE-CB 1))
f-5     (CB (ID-BUS B2) (NUM-CB 2) (STATE-CB 0))
f-6     (CB (ID-BUS B2) (NUM-CB 5) (STATE-CB 1))
f-7     (CB (ID-BUS B2) (NUM-CB 8) (STATE-CB 0))
f-8     (CB (ID-BUS B3) (NUM-CB 3) (STATE-CB 0))
f-9     (CB (ID-BUS B3) (NUM-CB 7) (STATE-CB 1))
f-10    (CB (ID-BUS B3) (NUM-CB 9) (STATE-CB 0))
f-14    (Connexion (ID-BUS B3) (CB-CLOSED 7) (CB-OPEN 3 9))
f-15    (Connexion (ID-BUS B2) (CB-CLOSED 5) (CB-OPEN 2 8))
f-16    (Connexion (ID-BUS B1) (CB-CLOSED 1 4 6) (CB-OPEN))
For a total of 14 facts.
CLIPS>
```

Alternately, you can populate the Connexion facts in a single rule firing:

```
(defrule populate-connexion
   =>
   (do-for-all-facts ((?cn Connexion)) 
                      (and (eq ?cn:CB-CLOSED (create$ nil)) (eq ?cn:CB-OPEN (create$ nil)))
      (bind ?closed (create$))
      (bind ?open (create$))
      (do-for-all-facts ((?cb CB)) (eq ?cb:ID-BUS ?cn:ID-BUS)
         (if (eq ?cb:STATE-CB 1)
            then
            (bind ?closed (create$ ?closed ?cb:NUM-CB))
            else
            (bind ?open (create$ ?open ?cb:NUM-CB))))
      (modify ?cn (CB-CLOSED ?closed) (CB-OPEN ?open)))))
```

Comment: Without you M.Riley, we do not know what we would become. Thank you very much.